# Is it possible to use iterate with call and agregate in the same sequence?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a scenario in which I need to iterate through an xml and call an endpoint multiple times. After that I need to aggregate the results and use a custom mediator on it. The problem is that all of this has to be done in a single sequence executed by a scheduled task.

Unfortunatelly agregate doesn't seem to wait for the responses. Is there anyway to do this without creating some kind of proxy on the side?

Here's my example code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="s_queue_kernel_dev" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <kernel.prepare/>
    <iterate continueParent="true"
        expression="//*[local-name()='request']" id="it1"
        sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <ser:getEntity xmlns:ser="http://services">
                            <ser:entityID>$1</ser:entityID>
                        </ser:getEntity>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml"
                            expression="./*[local-name()='entityId']" literal="false"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <kernel.log>
                    <operation>REQUEST</operation>
                    <description>{$body}</description>
                </kernel.log>
                <call blocking="false">
                    <endpoint key="gov:atena/endpoints/egida/entities.xml"/>
                </call>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <aggregate id="it1">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="//*[local-name()='getEntityReturn']" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <kernel.log>
                <operation>RESPONSE</operation>
                <description>{$body}</description>
            </kernel.log>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
    <kernel.log>
        <operation>SUCCESS</operation>
        <description>{$body}</description>
    </kernel.log>
    <kernel.success/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Can you clarify more on what do you mean by "Unfortunatelly agregate doesn't seem to wait for the responses."? It seems what you have done is correct, but I cannot understand what is the exact issue you are having.

Comment: The issue is that the kernel.log mediator inside the onComplete in aggregate doesn't execute at all, and the kernel.log at the end (SUCCESS) logs the original request instead of the aggregated responses.

Comment: I couldn't see an enclosing element tag to aggregate the messages inside one tag.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see an enclosing element tag to aggregate the messages.
Following is a working example. Please modify your sequence accordingly.

```
<sequence>
        <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
        <iterate continueParent="true" id="check" expression="//Samples/Sample">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <call>
                        <endpoint>
                            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e2aaab832000066001c6d06"/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </call>
                    <property name="info" scope="default">
                        <ns:Information xmlns:ns="www.asankatechtalks.com"/>
                    </property>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </iterate>
        <aggregate id="check">
            <completeCondition>
                <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="$body/*[1]" enclosingElementProperty="info">
                <respond/>
            </onComplete>
        </aggregate>
    </sequence>
```

Comment: You can tryout with the following payload.
`<Samples>
 <Sample>1</Sample>
 <Sample>2</Sample>
 <Sample>3</Sample>
 <Sample>4</Sample>
 <Sample>5</Sample>
</Samples>`